# Doubt related to heat in an isothermal process and phase change

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

This might be a silly doubt but definition of heat is energy transferred due to temperature difference so if there is no temperature difference there is no heat so in an isothermal process heat absorbed/released by the system should be zero by definition since  change in temperature $\Delta T = 0$.But applying first law i.e $\Delta Q = \Delta W + \Delta U $ we know $\Delta U=0$ (since $\Delta U = nR\frac f2 \Delta T$) so $\Delta Q =nRTln(V_2/V_1) + 0$. So according to first argument $\Delta Q = 0$ and according to the second argument $\Delta Q \not= 0 $ ( which is I think the correct one since it is given in my book).How do we know that 1st argument is wrong and second argument is correct.Similarly during phase change no change in temperature is there so why do we say heat  is absorbed by ice(at $0^\circ$C) to become water(at $0^\circ$C).

So I have two doubts 1st heat in an isothermal process and 2nd heat in a phase transfer in both the cases temperature difference is zero but heat is non-zero which should be zero according to the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your central question is: How can we assume that a surrounding environment (at temperature $T$) maintains an isothermal system at $T$ and also call the exchanged energy “heat,” if “heat” is energy transfer driven by a temperature *difference*?

The answer is: There are temperature differences in practice, but we ignore them as negligible.

This is one of those cases where the assumptions we make to simplify the problem result in a technical contradiction, because objects at exactly the same temperature shouldn’t be able to heat one another.

Let’s say the heat into the system is positive, as it might be in your ice-melting example. What’s really happening is that the endothermic melting tends to cool the rest of the ice.

This introduces a temperature gradient that drives heat flow from the surroundings. It the melting rate is low (and thermodynamics often assumes everything to be infinitely slow, so we can idealize states as equilibrium states), then the ice never cools all that much. To avoid having to model the kinetics of the heat transfer, we simply assume that it doesn’t cool at all—but that heat still flows to replace the enthalpy of melting.

This makes many equations simpler by retaining $T$ instead of having to incorporate some spatiotemporal variation $T-\Delta T(x,y,z,t)$.

In addition, a slight heat flow over a long time adds up to a nonnegligible number, so we retain the balance between heat, work, and internal energy that’s need to satisfy conservation.

And again, if the process is slow enough, the deviation from having to consider the temperature change can be brought arbitrarily close to zero. But if this strategy isn’t clearly explained, then the student who’s learned—correctly—that heat is driven by a temperature difference will become confused.

Answer (score 2):

The temperature difference is between the isothermal system and the surroundings, not a temperature difference within the isothermal system which, by definition, is zero. The system can be isothermal because it is undergoing a constant temperature phase change , or  because it is a thermal reservoir.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

An example of a isothermal process would be to put your system, say a gas confined by a piston in a cylinder, in a thermal bath at a fixed temperature $T$. If you vary the pressure on the piston, this results in the exchange of heat, without changing the final temperature of the system (since it is in a thermal bath); of course, if you want an ideal/reversible process, you have to vary the pressure infinitely slowly. Anyway, you can say that all the work involved results in heat exchange, in agreement, as you pointed out, with the First Law ($\Delta U=0$ because $\Delta T=0$, hence $\Delta Q=\Delta W=nRT\log{(V_2/V_1)}$).

Regarding the heat absorbed by melting ice, it is "used" by ice to dissolve the hydrogen bonds which are responsible for its solid structure, not to increase its own temperature.